# Visual Studio Git sln file merge conflicts

Tags: git, visual-studio

This cannot be impossible to fix but there is something wrong with my git workflow using Visual Studio (2017).  I have another dev that I share a solution with multiple projects with.  At the moment we are going through the code base and adding existing projects to the solution but when I push my branch (call it `DAL`) to the server (Bitbucket) and do a pull request to merge it into the `Development` branch, all goes well.  When he tries to do a similar operation from his branch (`Tests`), we always get a solution file merge conflict. There MUST be a way to add projects in different branches and merge them back into a `Development` branch without this headache right?  The only solution I could find is to go into the `Development` branch, create all the projects first, then branch to `Database` and `Tests` and add the associated project files.  This seems very obtuse to me but I can't seem to find a different way of doing it.  Seems like this should be so obvious but it is escaping me.  I did a thorough search for this question but found nothing that solves the problem - please bear with me because I know I can't be the only guy dealing with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is that you're trying to do it directly in bitbucket.  Merge conflicts are very common and not the end of the world.

See here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/resolve-merge-conflicts-704414003.html

I'd recommend merging `development` into `tests` locally and resolve the merge conflicts on your local machine.  Then push the newly merged `tests` branch to bitbucket.

Once you've done than, bit-bucket will let you merge `tests` back into `development`.

Comment: Thank you for your insight and quick response.  And normally I would agree that merge conflicts are not the end of the world but when we are dealing with solution files (.sln) that use guids to identify projects etc, it is very error prone, and thus I am relunctant to make changes.  In at least one instance, it left my solution file with duplicate projects that didn't have the correct files associated with them.  Would you say that I should merge `development` into `tests`, push `tests` and then do a pr?

Comment: That might be an option.  It depends on your PR process and what the approver will accept.  Ultimately the result should be the same.  I would say that if you see this regularly then the alternative is to avoid adding projects in parrallel.  Add one, merge into `develop` then branch and add another.

Comment: Hi Philip, looking back at this old question with the advantage of over a year's experience, you are right on the money.  In normal circumstances, there wouldn't be a use case for two separate devs adding different projects to a solution (typically) but in our case, we were taking over 100 stand alone projects (brown field development) and trying to create one over all solution.  Great feedback!